# Is there a way to pattern match against DateTime and Nullable<DateTime>?

Tags: f#

I've tried something like this:

```
type DateResult = | ValidDate of DateTime | NullableDate | BlahBlah

let validateDate entry =
    match entry with
    | :? DateTime as x -> ValidDate x // error here
    | :? Nullable<DateTime> as x -> NullableDate
    | _ BlahBlah
```

But this does not work. Is this possible? What is the recommended way of handling a problem like this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`DateTime` and `Nullable<DateTime>` are different types and compiler cannot infer what is the type of parameter `entry`. Use type annotation:

```
let validateDate (entry: obj) =
    match entry with
    | :? DateTime as x -> ValidDate x 
    | :? Nullable<DateTime> as x -> NullableDate
    | _ BlahBlah
```